# OpenCV image treatment using Camera2 on Android

Tags: android, image, opencv, video, camera

I recently develloped a camera application on Android using the new API Camera2.
It works pretty well. I capture a video when I click on a button, nothing complicated.
But now, I need to implement an Image treatment using OpenCV. 
To do this, I need to catch the image buffer, process it, then display it on my surface.

So I have multiple questions:

- Is it possible to do this based on Camera2 or I need to rewrite my project with the camera provided by OpenCV.
- If it's possible, somebody have a way to do this ?

Edit : I've seen that i can use an ImageReader to get the images from my surface. But how can i attach an ImageReader from my surface ? And how can i display the result ?

Thanks you for your answers. 
Ps : Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to find, there is not support on OpenCV for Camera2. The example above works with the deprecated Camera API.

Take a look on the OpenCV 3.0 book, link provided below.

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hb8FCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=opencv+android+camera2&source=bl&ots=6uLJkd02Q7&sig=n5rl8mz7uIMctB1EUGwhB80kcCo&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBWoVChMIvL3Ii_W0xwIVg7wUCh1lzgAa#v=onepage&q=opencv%20android%20camera2&f=false